# Tensorflow forward propagation extremely slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm encountering an issue in using tensorflow (0.12.1 and 0.11.0rc1 on two different machines), namely manually performing forward propagation and gradient computation being extremely slow (training works fine on the other hand).

In particular, calling `sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={...}` takes between 1 and 1.2 seconds for 1 image. For reference, the same architecture implemented in caffe' takes around 100-150 ms, which is coherent with the times reported in the paper I have reimplemented. A similar amount of time (~1.5s) is required for the backpropagation through the network via `tf.gradients`. Again, the same architecture in caffe takes around 1/10 of that time.

I checked the GPU usage during the forward prop to be sure that it was actually using the GPU and it correctly spikes during the `sess.run` (using a GTX TITAN Z with cuda 8 and a TITAN X with cuda 7.5 on the two machines respectively)

The fact that the same architecture (a fairly straightforward conv-deconv, https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06041) in caffe works fine makes me think that there is something wrong in either my tensorflow code or configuration, but I have no clue on where to start. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Edit: link at the code added.

Tensorflow network and forward function: http://pastebin.com/y9jKBdsV (disregard the fact that the forward function looks like a dcgan, the problem persists regardless)

Caffe prototxt and forward function: http://pastebin.com/DqWdbHU8

Comment: Do you have a link to the source code

Comment: Your question is too broad, adding code (probably for both the caffe and tensorflow implementations) would make your question more likely to be answered.

Comment: Tensorflow network and forward function: http://pastebin.com/y9jKBdsV (disregard the fact that the forward function looks like a dcgan)

Caffe prototxt and forward function: http://pastebin.com/DqWdbHU8

Comment: The source code appears to have been taken off pastebin